# Is there a lowermost energy limit to a hybrid orbitals mixing?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-spin, orbitals

As I am currently starting to learn the formation of chemical bonds from a orbital perspective, bonding from from the lowering of the overall energy of the atomic orbitals. As this is an introductory level to this and there is no explanation behind the mechanics and mathematics of this, it leaves me pondering as to how low the energy can go in this. I imagine that it will not reach zero or a negative value (This is just gut instinct).
Can this energy value be estimated or calculated?

Comment: I looked your other questions too, and think that you might found these ideas usable; https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312524491_STATES_OF_MATTER_defined_from_The_Speed_of_Light